# Carcassonne: how to score city points when tied

Tags: carcassonne, scoring

The question is explicitly about a situation when two or more players have the same number of knights in a closed city.

The instructions say: "In case of a tie, the tied players each score the points.". So, the question is how many.

Let's assume the closed city is worth 10 points and is being closed during the game. **Should all players get 10 points (each player) or should they get a split (5 points for each)?** Or maybe any other way to count those points..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**When multiple players score a feature, each player gets the full amount.**

There is only one way to score a feature, and if the rule says that each player scores that feature, each player will get the full amount of points. Every feature that can be shared (city, road, farm) has the potential to have a number of points such that an even split would be impossible to begin with.

For example, finished cities with a cathedral triple its score, so you can end up with an odd score for that city, making it impossible to evenly split between two players.

Comment: In polish instructions there's a rule describing splitting points from roads in a way Hackworth describes, so it seems even more legit.

Comment: Triple? Wasn't it 2 pt for each tile or shield without a Cathedral -> 3 pt each with one (or two)? So 1.5x, not 3x.

Comment: @ilkkachu The baseline score for a city is the number of tiles plus number of shields. Finishing the city without cathedral doubles that score, finishing it with cathedral triples it. We are saying the same thing, you just took a different baseline.

Answer (score 6):

Interpreting the sentence as regular English, and comparing it with the official rules in other languages, lead me to believe that **all players get 10 points**. There's no splitting involved.

[Here](https://www.thegameroom.nl/local/userfiles/sweet_uploads/Carcassonne_spelregels_Nederlands.pdf) is the Dutch version; the emphasized word means 'full', i.e. ten points in your example.

> Bij een gelijke stand krijgen alle spelers met de meeste horigen het **volle** aantal punten.

Comment: Just found it. In older version of instructions in polish there's a rule describing spliting points from roads. It says both players get full number of points

Answer (score 4):

Z-Man Games [English rules](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/d5/20/d5208d61-8583-478b-a06d-b49fc9cd7aaa/zm7810_carcassonne_rules.pdf) for the [current edition](https://www.zmangames.com/en/products/carcassonne/) (p. 5, bottom of page):

> If there are multiple meeples in a single scored feature, the player with the most meeples is awarded full points and
> all other players receive nothing. When more than one player have the most meeples in a scored feature, **the tied
> players all score full points**.

And there's an example under it of a tile being placed to connect two roads, completing it with four tiles:

> Since this
> completes the road, it is now
> scored and *both you and the other
> player score 4 points*. Then, you
> both take your meeple back

I have no recollection of that having ever been different between the various editions of the game (or the variants, either).